# Is possible to change the value of '.' without actually change the current directory?

Tags: directory, java

Can I make the value of `.` to be a different directory from the current directory?

#### Background

I'm learning Java. In the directory of my program, I have two sub-directories, `src` and `bin`. Every time I have to compile my code, I enter `src` to call `javac`, because of the path of the Java classes imported in the source file, and I specify the destination for storing the .class files to be `../bin`. When I run my code, I enter `../bin`, to call `java`.

When I need to modify my code and recompile, I enter `../src` again for running `javac`. Then I need to enter `../bin` to run my program. Constantly changing my code leads to constantly switching my current directory between `src` and `bin`.

#### Questions

- I wonder if the organization of my program files (source and executables) is incorrect, for example, shall I put all source and executable files under the same directory, so that no need to switch?
- However that seems unwise, since it will mix source and executables in the same directory?

Comment: I just figure out that I can go under the parent of `src` and `bin`, and specify `src` to `javac -cp` and `bin` to `java -cp`. But adding `bin` to `java -cp` means `java -cp bin bin.mycode`? I didn't have `package bin.mycode` in my source, but just `package mycode`.

Comment: have you consider 1) use of `cd -` when switching, 2) have two tty (if it is possible) ?

Comment: @jimmij: I see.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re really asking, but maybe these will help: (1) In bash, at least, if you set `CDPATH=$HOME` (or add the value of `$HOME`, colon-delimited, to your current value of `CDPATH`), then you can say `cd bin` from ***anywhere in the file system*** and it will take you to `~/bin` (i.e., you don’t need to type `../`). And, of course, `cd src` will work the same way. (2) If, in the `src` directory, you type `ln -s ../bin b`, then you can type `cd b` (from the `src` directory) to go to `~/bin`. (And, of course, vice versa.) (3) You can define aliases for `cd ~/bin` and `cd ~/src`.

Comment: (4) In bash, at least, if you say `shopt -s autocd`, then you can simply type the name of a directory, and (if there isn’t a command by the same name) the shell will go to that directory. In conjunction with the `CDPATH` trick, this would mean that you could type merely `bin` and you would go to `~/bin`. Of course, this isn’t really any more powerful than defining aliases. (5) I almost overlooked it, so, in case you did, too: @Archemar suggested having two windows (ttys), keeping one in each directory. (There are many keyboard shortcuts for switching between windows.)

Comment: “Change the value of .” doesn't make sense. I read the body of your question and I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Please edit your question, including its title, to make it clear.

Comment: @Gilles: Never mind. I had some brain strain when I asked the questions.

Answer (score 4):

`.` is not a variable with a value.  It is a (special) file in the filesystem.  You cannot change it.